# Nginx regexp all paths expect

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-location

I have a 3 type of paths `/api`, `/`,`/some_path_here`

If user have requested page with empty path (`/`) I want to redirect to login .

So I have a config file  look like this

```
 location /api {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


        location /[0-9a-z]  {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
          root /var/www/cabinet/client/dist;
        }

        location / {
          return 301 https://my_domain.com/login;
        }
```

But when trying to request `https://my_domain.com/` its redirect to `https://my_domain.com/login` with error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Which of the given locations is supposed to handle `/login`?

Comment: the locations which contain regexp

Comment: Then you must indicate that you wanna it be treated as regex, add ~* in front of the expression.

Comment: the same result.

Comment: Your regex currently matches a slash and a lower case letter or digit.

Comment: yes i need everything except `/api`

Comment: Then perhaps you need something like `location ~* ^/[0-9a-z]+$`. At present your regex would never match `/login`.

Comment: not working! the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
location /api {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
          root /var/www/cabinet/client/dist;
        }

        location = / {
          return 301 $scheme://$server_name/login/;
        }
```